# bootstrap windows winrm fails with network error

Tags: windows, chef-infra, bootstrapping, knife, winrm

I am trying to bootstrap a windows winrm using knife command.

I have enabled the tcp port 5985.
But i still get the following error:

ERROR: Network Error: Connection refused - connect(2) (http://:5985)

I am able to remotely login to the machine as well by providing username and password

I could not resolve. Has anyone come across this problem and found a solution?

Comment: Have you enabled winrm on the target machine?
Why is the host missing from the URL you give above?

Comment: Yes it has been enabled

Comment: Can you telnet from your workstation to the remote host at port 5985, e.g. `telnet remote_host 5985`

Comment: Yes i tried with the command : error is as follows:     Could not open connection to the host on port 5985 .connection failed.

Comment: If you cannot telnet to 5985, either you don't have winrm configured on the remote, or firewall is blocking it.

Answer (score 8):

Check that you can `telnet remote_host 5985`. This should open a dumb session into which you can enter "quit". If not, look again at how you have enabled winrm and the firewall on the remote host.

I got winrm bootstrap working on Windows VMs *which did not have firewall enabled* like this:

All the following on the remote Windows machine you want to bootstrap...

Enable winrm:

```
winrm quickconfig -q
```

Enable and start the firewall service (so we can successfully config winrm):

```
sc config mpssvc start= demand
sc start mpssvc
```

Configure winrm per chef recommendations:

```
winrm set winrm/config/winrs @{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="300"}
winrm set winrm/config @{MaxTimeoutms="1800000"}
winrm set winrm/config/service @{AllowUnencrypted="true"}
winrm set winrm/config/service/auth @{Basic="true"}
```

Stop the firewall service again:

```
sc stop mpssvc
```

... or configure it to allow to winrm connections from the workstation.

Now, on your workstation, validate the set up:

Validate that remote host is listening on default winrm port

```
telnet remote_host 5985
```

(If connection is successful, a blank telnet session will open. You can enter "quit" to exit it.)

Optionally validate that knife winrm can connect to the remote host (e.g. to list the c:\ directory)

```
knife winrm -m remote_host -x remote_user -P remote_password 'dir c:\'
```

Bootstrap the node

```
knife bootstrap windows winrm remote_host -x remote_user -P remote_password
```

Since you ask for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources here are the references I found useful when figuring out how to get winrm bootstrap to work:

- http://docs.opscode.com/install_windows.html
- http://docs.opscode.com/plugin_knife_windows.html
- http://developer.rackspace.com/blog/step-by-step-walkthrough-to-using-chef-to-bootstrap-windows-nodes-on-the-rackspace-cloud.html

Comment: After I execute the following command :  sc stop mpssvc  , the remote machine is getting disconnected and unable to connect only after that

Comment: even after executing the first four steps , when telnet command is executed - the remote host cant be connected.

Comment: Apologies in advance, but you are executing the winrm configuration on the remote Windows box that you want to bootstrap, right? Not on your workstation.

Comment: I have followed all the steps and achieving some progress but the last one, ```knife boostrap```, still doesn't work. I get this error ```RuntimeError: Knife-Windows < 1.0 does not support validatorless bootstraps```.

Comment: johnnyjava.net - I received the RuntimeError: Knife-Windows < 1.0 does not support validatorless bootstraps when I was running the command outside of my chef-repo directory where my chef repository is defined.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar issue.One of the reasons for this might be you knife-windows gem is not installed in expected location.

knife-windows resolves target hostname.if its not properly installed winrm knife cant resolve targetname.So to overcome this install knife-windows as below

To install the knife windows plugin using RubyGems, run the following command:

> ```
>     $ /opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem install knife-windows
> ```

if properly installed you should be able to find knife-windows at      /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/